# Multiple templates in XSLT based on page level

Tags: xslt

I am working with a CMS, which allows the use of XSLT for the navigation. The design dictates a navigation with three different levels, and with somewhat different markup for each one. "No sweat", said the optimistic developer, "I'll just hack it together with XSLT. I mean, how hard can it be?". This was my first mistake.

Let's cut to the chase:

**XSLT**

```
  <xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">    
    <xsl:if test="count(//Page) > 0">
      <ul class="floatLeft">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
          <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="//Page">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <li>

      <xsl:if test="count(Page)">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Subpage">
            <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>

    </li>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="//Subpage">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <li class="test">
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
```

My idea is, that the first level should use the "Page" template, and all it's subpages should use the "Subpage" template. Instead, all the items after the second in the first level, use the "Subpage" template. If I remove that template, it correctly displays the whole first level — but no sublevels. My uneducated guess is that something is wrong in the if statement inside the Page template.

Does that make sense?

I know HTML better than my native spoken language, but I'm a rookie when it comes to XSLT. I couldn't even figure what to search for, so if this problem has been covered somewhere else, guide me O' mighty wise men.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing an example of your source xml.

Comment: The source is magically delivered by the CMS. I'll see if I can figure out how to extract it somehow.

Comment: Are there really _Subpage_ elements inside the _Page_ elements, or are they called _Page_ too? The second template looks strange as it counts the _Page_ child elements but tries to apply templates for _Subpage_ children.

Comment: @Martin Ah, not necessarily. I made that one. My logic was "if this is a subpage to the current level, apply the "Subpage" template". As I said, I'm a total rookie when it comes to XSLT. Maybe this needs more research on my part ...

Comment: OK, in this case it would definitely help if you could provide an example XML input document and the output to be generated from it.

Comment: @Nix: You can get a copy of the source XML simply by applying the identity transformation: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html

Comment: @Martin, Filburt, Dimitre Notatchev:
I managed to solve the problem (see my answer). Thank you all for your help, and sorry for the vague question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like so:

```
    <xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">

    <xsl:if test="count(//Page) > 0">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
          <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="//Page">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </a>


      <xsl:if test="count(./Page)">

        <xsl:for-each select="./Page">

          <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="./Page">
                <a href="{@FriendlyHref}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </a>
            </xsl:for-each>

         </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
```

The XML is simple enough. It's simply `<Page />` nodes nested into eachother.

```
<Page ID="99" MenuText="Branding days " Href="Default.aspx?ID=99" FriendlyHref="/en-GB/Corporate/Branding-days.aspx" ShowInSitemap="False" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" ChildCount="3" class="L2">
```

If anyone have a cleaner solution, let me know, but as for now it works as expected.